# Dynamically build the 'Filename' and the 'Extension' of an ItemGroup into 1 line

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

I am executing a command on a set of NuGet files within my build script.  However, the [MSBuild Item Metadata](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164313.aspx) doesn't have a field that contains BOTH the 'Filename' and the 'Extension'.

I want to batch execute a command without having to hard-code the file extension...but I am having trouble doing so.

**MY QUESTION:**
How do I execute each command separately without burying the file extension in the text of the command?

**MY CODE:**

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <NuSpecFiles Include="$(SourceFolder)*.nuspec"></NuSpecFiles>
  </ItemGroup>

  <Target Name="GenerateNuSpecFile" Condition="'@(NuSpecFiles->Count())' &gt; 0">
    <!-- YUCK: The FileExtension is buried in the command -->
    <Exec Command="nuget pack %(NuSpecFiles.Filename).nuspec" WorkingDirectory="$(DropFolder)"/>
  </Target>
```

Comment: did you try %(NuSpecFiles.Filename)%(NuSpecFiles.Extension)?

Comment: No...I always tried staying within the parenthesis (in various manners).  Your method works...answer below and I will mark it!  Thanks...this was driving me nuts.

Comment: Let me put it in answer section of other people's reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try following

```
%(NuSpecFiles.Filename)%(NuSpecFiles.Extension)
```